# How to write the below Android(A-Java) code in the same way of iOS(Objective-C)

Tags: android, ios, arrays, stream, byte

Below is the piece of Android code working fine, i have to write the same login and type in iOS, how to write, specially Base64 Encoding with imageBytes.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encodedImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below would be the exact equivalent..

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:byteArrayData];
NSData *imageBytes = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *encodedImage = [imageBytes base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: Thanks :-)  will check and revert